# convert dataframe to dictionary excluding the ID

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

My aim is to create a nested dictionary but I'm getting random number as parent key. This is what I have gone so far :

```
result = result[['column1', 'column2','column3']]
result = result.to_dict('index')

all_result = {'ERR_CODE' : 0, 'ERR_MESSAGE' :'No error'}
all_result['LOC'] = result
```

The result I received :

```
{
  "ERR_CODE": 0,
  "ERR_MESSAGE": "No error",
  "LOC": {
    "792": {  #random number or possibly the row id
       "column1": "abc",
       "column2": "123",
       "column3": "def"
    }
  }
}
```

Expected result :

```
{
  "ERR_CODE": 0,
  "ERR_MESSAGE": "No error",
  "LOC": {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  }
}
```

I can't use `pop(792)` in this case because the number will be random. Is there any way I can use `pop` using index? or any other alternatives..

**UPDATE**
The answer given fix the above problem but what if the result has multiple child below it, such as (expected result):

```
{
  "ERR_CODE": 0,
  "ERR_MESSAGE": "No error",
  "LOC": {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  },
  {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  }
}
```

I changed based on the solution to [0:] as it gives me this :

```
{
  "ERR_CODE": 0,
  "ERR_MESSAGE": "No error",
  "LOC": [                    # list
  {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  },
  {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  }
 ]                           #list
}
```

I dont want the `[ ]` in the result.

Comment: what you mean you dont want [ ] ?

Comment: what is your expected outcome if has multiple child objects?

Comment: Not in a list form i guess @RajithThennakoon

Comment: I showed you above my expected result with multiple child @RajithThennakoon

Comment: you can't create objects like this ` "LOC": {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  },
  {
    "column1": "abc",
    "column2": "123",
    "column3": "def"
  }` .if you have multiple child objects it should be inside a list,or you have to create new key,value pair.

Comment: understand. I accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can return records as list assign

```
result = list(result.to_dict("index").values())
```